# User Can not Login Magento Store with Varnish

Tags: php, magento, cookies, varnish

I have a Magento store with Varnish server cache. the user can not log in my Magento store by IE. Its fine with other browsers, but only have the issue with IE. After a user enters correct user/password and clicks login button, its showing login page without any error.

I have check the cookies, onlye one "frontend" cookie, so should not be caused by duplicated frontend cookies issue.

I have set 
Cookies domain: www.domain.com
Cookies path: /

Cache Extension

Nexcessnet_Turpentine

Thanks for hlep

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a straight answer to your concern, but [Turpentine plugin is not a full page cache](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/turpentine-is-not-full-page-cache), and unfortunately Magento 1.x is not really Varnish-able for first page requests by a guest visitor.

So my advice is going with a full page cache plugin. 
Consider the "always-uncached first visit" behaviour of Turpentine+Varnish. Any full page cache plugin will provide for a better performance overall.

By choosing another plugin, you will avoid all the issues connected with Varnish configuration and it will work faster anyway. So why bother with Turpentine?

Disclaimer: I love Varnish and in all other case I would recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a look and try other full page cache plugin.